# how to decompress big file of more than 100mb in not using any external libraries

Tags: c#, .net-core, gzip, gzipstream

I've tried using NuGet packages to extract the tgz file but the tgz contains the file with names having unsupported characters to a file name eg: 1111-11-1111:11:11.111.AA

verified this issue using the sharpcompress lib.

so I had to follow the gist link below

https://gist.github.com/ForeverZer0/a2cd292bd2f3b5e114956c00bb6e872b

this is the link I've followed to extract the tgz file. This is a really nice piece of code and is working well. but when I try to extract big size tgz files more than 100MB an error is getting like the stream is too long.

[image: error in memory stream]

[image: detail error]

Comment: MemoryStream has maximum capacity of about 2GB, you are trying to write more data there.

Comment: yes but the data the stream has to hold more than that, I added a count inside the do-while loop and it is breaking when the count reaches 524287

Comment: This question is a little confusing, you dont want to use external libraries, but you are. Also why not just extract it to a `FileStream`? Why do you need to do this in a `MemoryStream` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error means that you are trying to feed too much bytes into `MemoryStream`, which has a maximum capacity of `int.MaxValue` (about 2GB).

If you cannot find a suitable library and want to work with provided code, then it can be modified as follows.

Note that entire `GZipStream` is first copied to `MemoryStream`. Why? As comment in the code states:

```
// A GZipStream is not seekable, so copy it first to a MemoryStream
```

However, in subsequent code, only two operations are used which require stream to be seekable: `stream.Seek(x, SeekOrigin.Current)` (where x is always positive), and `stream.Position`. Both of this operations can be emulated by reading the stream, without seeking. For example, to seek forward you can read that amount of bytes and discard:

```
private static void FakeSeekForward(Stream stream, int offset) {
    if (stream.CanSeek)
        stream.Seek(offset, SeekOrigin.Current);
    else {
        int bytesRead = 0;
        var buffer = new byte[offset];
        while (bytesRead < offset)
        {
            int read = stream.Read(buffer, bytesRead, offset - bytesRead);
            if (read == 0)
                throw new EndOfStreamException();
            bytesRead += read;
        }
    }
}
```

And to track current stream position you can just store amount of bytes read. Then we can remove converation to `MemoryStream` and code from the link becomes:

```
public class Tar
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Extracts a <i>.tar.gz</i> archive to the specified directory.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filename">The <i>.tar.gz</i> to decompress and extract.</param>
    /// <param name="outputDir">Output directory to write the files.</param>
    public static void ExtractTarGz(string filename, string outputDir)
    {
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
            ExtractTarGz(stream, outputDir);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Extracts a <i>.tar.gz</i> archive stream to the specified directory.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="stream">The <i>.tar.gz</i> to decompress and extract.</param>
    /// <param name="outputDir">Output directory to write the files.</param>
    public static void ExtractTarGz(Stream stream, string outputDir)
    {
        using (var gzip = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            // removed convertation to MemoryStream
            ExtractTar(gzip, outputDir);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Extractes a <c>tar</c> archive to the specified directory.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filename">The <i>.tar</i> to extract.</param>
    /// <param name="outputDir">Output directory to write the files.</param>
    public static void ExtractTar(string filename, string outputDir)
    {
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
            ExtractTar(stream, outputDir);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Extractes a <c>tar</c> archive to the specified directory.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="stream">The <i>.tar</i> to extract.</param>
    /// <param name="outputDir">Output directory to write the files.</param>
    public static void ExtractTar(Stream stream, string outputDir) {
        var buffer = new byte[100];
        // store current position here
        long pos = 0;
        while (true) {
            pos += stream.Read(buffer, 0, 100);
            var name = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer).Trim('\0');
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
                break;
            FakeSeekForward(stream, 24);
            pos += 24;
            
            pos += stream.Read(buffer, 0, 12);
            var size = Convert.ToInt64(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, 12).Trim('\0').Trim(), 8);
            FakeSeekForward(stream, 376);
            pos += 376;

            var output = Path.Combine(outputDir, name);
            if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(output)))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(output));
            if (!name.Equals("./", StringComparison.InvariantCulture)) {
                using (var str = File.Open(output, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)) {
                    var buf = new byte[size];
                    pos += stream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                    str.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                }
            }

            var offset = (int) (512 - (pos % 512));
            if (offset == 512)
                offset = 0;
            FakeSeekForward(stream, offset);
            pos += offset;
        }
    }

    private static void FakeSeekForward(Stream stream, int offset) {
        if (stream.CanSeek)
            stream.Seek(offset, SeekOrigin.Current);
        else {
            int bytesRead = 0;
            var buffer = new byte[offset];
            while (bytesRead < offset)
            {
                int read = stream.Read(buffer, bytesRead, offset - bytesRead);
                if (read == 0)
                    throw new EndOfStreamException();
                bytesRead += read;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i had tried this out but the files are not extracting correctly getting this exception

long size = Convert.ToInt64(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, 12).Trim('\0').Trim(), 8);


System.FormatException: 'Could not find any recognizable digits.'

Comment: Are you sure you copied the whole code? I tested it with couple of tgz files I had, was working fine. If you can publish failing file somewhere, I can have a look.

Comment: I mean the whole `Tar` class provided in last code block in answer.

Comment: no files are working for me

i tried using this sample file
https://developer.blender.org/F22159

Comment: @user11738472 yes there was a small bug in my code (forgot to increment `pos` after last `FakeSeekForward`), fixed now. Now my code seems to behave the same as you linked. On my machine they both fail on your sample file though, because some names are directories and not file names (and linked code always tries to create a file with provided name), but I guess you know how to handle this already.